# Can Stage3d be used to perform parallel calculations?

Tags: actionscript-3, stage3d, pixel-bender

I used to program maps in AS3 like you, but then I took a Pixel Bender in the knee. Since then I have been using Pixel Bender to do parallel calculations on arrays. Can Stage3D be used for this?

Example of using Pixel Bender for calculation:

http://wonderfl.net/c/eFp0/

My goal is to get a vector of `[x1, y1, x2, y,2 , . . ., xn, yn]` and return a vector of `[f(x1), f(y1), f(x2), f(y2), . . . ,f(xn), f(yn)]`. More like `f(x1, y1).x , f(x1,y1).y`. I am sure you get the general idea.

What we normally call a map. Here is a thorough explaination.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_%28higher-order_function%29

I noticed that with Pixel Bender I can accomplish this with a speed boost of 10x. Is there any way to do the same thing with Stage3D.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike other languages such as c++, I'm not aware of a way to direct assembly instructions to the GPU beyond [Program3D Shaders with Adobe Graphics Assembly Language](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display3D/Program3D.html).

> Program bytecode can be created using the Pixel Bender 3D offline
>   tools. It can also be created dynamically. The AGALMiniAssembler class
>   is a utility class that compiles AGAL assembly language programs to
>   AGAL bytecode. The class is not part of the runtime. When you upload
>   the shader programs, the bytecode is compiled into the native shader
>   language for the current device (for example, OpenGL or Direct3D). The
>   runtime validates the bytecode on upload.
>
> The programs run whenever the Context3D drawTriangles() method is
>   invoked. The vertex program is executed once for each vertex in the
>   list of triangles to be drawn. The fragment program is executed once
>   for each pixel on a triangle surface.

Not approaching the performance you are obtaining with Pixel Bender, it should be noted that you could leverage ActionScript [Workers](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Worker.html) to parallelize your functors.

> A Worker object represents a *worker*, which is a virtual instance of
>   the Flash runtime. Each Worker instance controls and provides access
>   to the lifecycle and shared data of a single worker.
>
> This capability of simultaneously executing multiple sets of code
>   instructions is known as *concurrency*.

With Adobe Premium Features, Alchemy / FlasCC, XC APIs, Pixel Bender, and ActionScript Next on the way, it's an exciting time for the rapidly progressing Flash platform.

Comment: Hi Jason, Pixel Bender 3D is what I needed. I wish to thank you sincerely.

Comment: I tested pixel bender 3d and I cannot seem to find a quick way to get the data back from the stage and into a vector? Do you happen to know any way to accomplish that?

Comment: @ArthurWulfWhite I'm not sure, but perhaps [FlasCC](http://gaming.adobe.com/technologies/flascc/) (formerly Alchemy) may be more inline with things you wish to accomplish.

Comment: pixel bender 3d is designed to make writing AGAL shader kernels easier. The only output from these kernels is to a framebuffer. You _can_ provide a BitmapData as a frameBuffer prior to the Context3D::drawTriangles call, and then access the pixels as color, but that will only get you integer precision...